# Как работают декоратор в js?

Tags: javascript

Как работает декоратор,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как работает декоратор!Мы перезаписываем функцию slow другой функцией,как она сохраняет в памяти изначальную функцию

Comment: Пожалуйста приложите код как текстом, а не фоткой

Comment: То есть мы в slow возвращаем анонимную функцию тем самым ее перезаписываем,не могу понять как result = func(x) запомнила старую функцию.Теперь при вызове slow(1) как она обращается к функции slow,а не к анонимной функции которую мы вернули через замыкание

Comment: Публикуйте ваш код как текст, а не картинку